I don't understand how removeAll function works in viewController.navigationController.viewControllers
So here's the original code
if let vc = PaybillViewController.newInstance(router: router,
                                                          environment: DependencyResolver.shared.appEnvironment,
                                                          transferSharedViewModel: DependencyResolver.shared.transferSharedViewModel,
                                                          favoriteSharedViewModel: DependencyResolver.shared.favoriteSharedViewModel) as? PaybillViewController {
                
                viewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                viewController.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAll { navigationViewController in
                    return !(navigationViewController
                        .isKind(of: MainTabbarViewController.self)) || !(navigationViewController.isKind(of: PaybillViewController.self))
                }
            }

The part I have a problem with is the return part
The original viewControllers stack after calling viewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) are:
0: MaintabbarViewController
1: PaybillTransactionViewController
2: PaybillPreviewController
3: PaybillSummaryViewController
4: PaybillViewController
After the removeAll function. The screen displays a black screen and It deinit removed all the remaining unopened ViewController in the MainTabbarViewController
So, after a while, I tried changing the return part to:
!(navigationViewController
                        .isKind(of: MainTabbarViewController.self) || navigationViewController.isKind(of: PaybillViewController.self))

And it worked as intended.
With the viewControllers stack changes to:
0: MaintabbarViewController
1: PaybillViewController
I just don't understand how that work. And if someone can enlighten me it'd be truly appreciated. Or just point me to the right documentation for this sort of thing would be good as well.
It worked now. I don't need to solve it. But I don't understand how it worked.

What did you change? I don't see any difference between the return statements of the two code snippets you showed.

Why wouldn't you use popToViewController instead?

When you remove all view controllers from the navigation stack, there's no view controllers to show on the screen anymore, and the screen is black. If the view controllers are only retained by the navigation controller, after you clear the stack, the view controllers will be released from the memory. RTFM, as they used to say: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller.

@Sweeper I'm sorry but I edited the question too much and I forget to recheck. But the original return statements should be !(navigationViewController                         .isKind(of: MainTabbarViewController.self)) || !(navigationViewController.isKind(of: PaybillViewController.self))

@sonle I don't have the destination viewController in the original navigation stacks. I have to push in it and then remove unwanted viewController from the stack.

When you use the two not operators, you need to combine them with an and &&, not an or - ||.
Any given view controller passed to the closure is going to be either:

A MainTabbarViewController
A PaybillViewController
Something else

It can't be two of these things at the same time.
When you OR the two NOTs, at least one subclause will always be true, and the view controller will be removed:
Input                         | !MainTabBar | !Paybill |  OR   | AND
----------------------------------------------------------------------
MainTabBarViewController      |    false    |   true   | true  | false         
PaybillViewController         |    true     |   false  | true  | false
SomethingElse                 |    true     |   true   | false | true

Any time the result is true the view controller will be removed from the array.

I've tried this. It worked as intended and I understand how it worked now. Thank you!
